# Unable to run .Net Core app under IISExpress under VS2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'v created new simple app with `dotnet new angular` while I'm, next I'm trying to start it under VS2017 with IISExpress. 
Chrome window is opened with "Visual Studio JavaScript/TypeScript debug..." window, and nothing happens...
If I do breakpoint in `Program.Main` it would not be hit until I close Chrome window. 
After closing the Chrome application is started.

So it looks like Chrome process prevents IIS from application start... really I'm confused. This used to work yesterday...

.Net Core SDK is 1.0.4

VS2017 is 15.2

Comment: If you change your debugging browser to FireFox, or another browser does it work? I've encountered a similar problem today, when the same process was was working yesterday, changing debugging browser worked for me.

Comment: Had no chance to test... I'v just installed Update 3 for VS2017, and it has solved my problem, for now...

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me once. I ran it by some other way and then came back and tried running via IIS. You can also try clean.

One of the ways to build is to cd to your project in command prompt, and use the `dotnet run` command. Another way is, go to your launchsettings.json file and create a new profile with slightly different values and try running it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappear after updating to VS2017.3 =\